# How to use Nmap as a port knocking client?

Tags: nmap, ctf, port-knocking

I want to use Nmap for port knocking on CTF machines, so I've read the manual for configuring it properly:

```
nmap <ip> -p <port1>,<port2>,... -r --max-retries 0 --max-parallelism 1
```

In particular, `-r` ensures ports are scanned in the listed order, `--max-retries 0` ensures that ports are not probed more than once, and `max-parallelism 1` ensures that only a single thread runs.

However, the above Nmap command fails to open the hidden service. If I instead use the following port knocking client everything just works:

https://github.com/grongor/knock

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use nmap instead of a tool specifically made to generate custom packets like `hping`?

Comment: There are so many other tools to do this. And since nmap isn't working for you, then you should switch to a tool that does.

Answer (score 0):

The knock script sets the socket to 'non-blocking'. Non-blocking in python is the same as setting the timeout to 0 - that is, don't wait for a response. The TCP protocol defaults to 'blocking' - i.e wait for a response.

From Knock git the relevant line is: `s.setblocking(False)`.

Try playing with the settings in nmap that set timeouts to 0:

https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html

`--min-rtt-timeout <time>, --max-rtt-timeout <time>, --initial-rtt-timeout <time> (Adjust probe timeouts)` or `--host-timeout <time> (Give up on slow target hosts)` (suspect it will be the first one though).

Also, you might find that having wireshark running in the background to capture all the traffic to and from the server being useful, as you'd have a record of what was being sent when using nmap and knock, you might uncover something that way by comparing the results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; however, the options doesn't seem to make Nmap work as a port knocking client (I've tried them all). In particular, the following error is given `Bogus --max-rtt-timeout argument specified, must be at least 5ms`, so I cannot set it to 0.

Comment: @Shuzheng Of course you can't set it to 0. Afterall, nmap is built to expect a response from a probe. That's the idea of it afterall. By trying to use nmap to do port knocking, you're doing the same as using a frozen banana to hammer in a nail. It's just not made for this task.